# What kind of errors exists in SQL querys for ROLLBACK?

Tags: sql, mysql, transactions, commit, rollback

For example:

```
insert into table( a, b ) values ('a','b') could generate the following error:

**a-b duplicate entry**
```

BUT here I can ignore this error selecting the ID of this values, then use this ID:

```
select ID from table where a = 'a' and b = 'b'
insert into brother( table ) values (ID)
```

Finally I could COMMIT the PROCEDURE. Look that this error isn't relevant for rollback if I need the ID.

The question is: what kind of errors will doing me to ROLLBACK the PROCEDURE???

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking, "What kind of errors can an INSERT statement cause that will make MySQL rollback a transaction?"

An INSERT that violates any constraint will cause a rollback. It could be foreign key constraint like you've outlined, but it could also be a UNIQUE constraint, or a CHECK constraint. (A CHECK constraint would probably be implemented as a trigger in MySQL.)

Trying to insert values that aren't valid (NULL in nonnullable columns, numbers that are out of range, invalid dates) might cause a rollback. But they might not, depending on the server configuration. (See link below.)

An INSERT can also fail due because it lacks permissions. That will also cause a rollback.

Some conditions that would cause a rollback on other platforms don't cause a rollback on MySQL.

> The options MySQL has when an error
>   occurs are to stop the statement in
>   the middle or to recover as well as
>   possible from the problem and
>   continue. By default, the server
>   follows the latter course. This means,
>   for example, that the server may
>   coerce illegal values to the closest
>   legal values.

That quote is from [How MySQL Deals with Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraints.html).

One of my favorite quotes from the MySQL documentation, [1.8.6.2. Constraints on Invalid Data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-invalid-data.html).

> MySQL enables you to store certain
>   incorrect date values into DATE and
>   DATETIME columns (such as '2000-02-31'
>   or '2000-02-00'). The idea is that it
>   is not the job of the SQL server to
>   validate dates.

Isn't that *cute*?